# How to grab API JSON from postman with angularjs

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, json

This is code for get API JSON from postman with AngularJS:

I have some problem with getting API JSON from Postman with Angular, can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Here is the Angular code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module("otobuus_app", []);
app.controller("index_controller", function($scope, $http, $q) {
    $scope.init = function() {
        angular.forEach(_result_kota, (val, index) => {
            var _options = "";
            angular.forEach(val.wilayahs, (val2) => {
                _options += '<option value=" '+ val2.idWilayah +' ">' + val2.namaWilayah + '</option>';
            });
            var _opt_group = '<optgroup label=" '+ val.namaProvinsi +'" >' + _options + '</optgroup>';
            $('#kotaAsal').append(_opt_group);
        })
        var _username = "otoMobile"; 
        var password = "Mutiara123";
        var _header = {Authorization: "Basic " + btoa(_username + ":" + password)};
        $http({
            method : "GET",
            header: _header,
            url: "http://dev.otodata.co.id:8181/mobile/kota/asal"
        }).then((response) => {
            $scope._result_kota = response._result_kota;
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    };
    //$scope.init();

    $(function() {
        var kota_asal = $('#asal2');
        $('#asal2').css('visibility','hidden');
        $('#asal1').val('');
        $('.kotaAsal').chosen({
            no_result_text: "Tidak ditemukan...",
            disable_search_threshold: 1000
        });
        $('#asal1').click(function() {
            $('#asal2').css('visibility','visible');
        });

        $('#kotaAsal').on('change', function() {
            var a = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
            $("#asal1").val($.trim(a))
                .parent('.mdl-textfield')
                .addClass('is-dirty')
                .removeClass('is-invalid');
            console.log($("#asal1").val());
            if ($("#asal1").val() != "") {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label col-xs-5">
        <input type="text" class="mdl-textfield__input" id="asal1">
        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for=""><p style="color: white;">Kota Asal</p></label>
    </div>

    <div id="asal2" class="col-xs-5 asal">
        <select class="kotaAsal" id="kotaAsal" style="width: 200px;">
            <optgroup ng-repeat="list_kota in _result_kota" label="{{ list_kota.namaProvinsi }}">
                <option ng-repeat="wilayah in list_kota.wilayahs" value="{{ wilayah.idWilayah }}">
                    {{ wilayah.namaWilayah }}
                </option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I debugged it in the browser, it shows service function is not show in display selected option data.

Comment: what do you mean about `grab API JSON from postman`? You mean the body or json response SAME with postman?

Comment: no... I mean when I grab url form my account postman, it did'nt work on my web.

Comment: Lumayan mudeng gue

Comment: can you help me Ananda...

Comment: In your code, `header` should be `headers`. I guess the issue here is the CORS issue.

Comment: Thanks Kris Roofe. I've change that... but it still not work. Data in json is not show